# Steps to add new Windows 2012R2 Server to RDS Deployment

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I have a new 2012R2 Server(call it server4) that I want to add to my RDS deployment. Here is our current configuration, all running 2012R2

- Server1: RDS License Server
- Server2: RD Connection Broker
- Server3: RDS Session Host
- Server4: New Server w/t RDS Session Host role installed.

question: What do I need to do so that Server4 can see the License Server?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found one way is to add the license info in group policy, under Computer Configuration->Admin Templates -> Windows components-> Remote Desktop Services-> Remote Desktop Session Host-> Licensing. If anyone has any other thoughts, techniques, reflections please reply